# php replacement route system

Tags: php, routes, replace

i need function in PHP for handle replacement something like this.

```
$pattern = ':foo/anotherString';

$replacement = array(
    'foo' => 'HelloMe'
);

bazFunction($pattern, $replacement); // return 'HelloMe/anotherString';
```

this method used in some frameworks as route patterns. i want to know which function handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do (5.3 required because of the closure)

```
function my_replace($pattern, $replacement) {
  // add ':' prefix to every key
  $keys = array_map(function($element) {
    return ':' . $element;
  }, array_keys($replacement));

  return str_replace($keys, array_values($replacement), $pattern);
}
```

You wouldn't need this function if you pass the stuff directly to `str_replace`

```
str_replace(array(':foo'), array('HelloMe'), ':foo/anotherString');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "foo/anotherString";
$replacement = array('foo','HelloMe');
$newString = str_replace($replacement[],,$string);
```

Comment: you missed the `:` in the `$string`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that php got the function for you...

```
str_replace ( ":foo", "HelloMe" , $pattern )
```

will give you this output: HelloMe/anotherString